Multilayer pads and track error
I'm working on a PCB and I struggle to understand why i get violation from this:

I did not modify the rules and the only clearance ones are a <0.254 mm on pretty much anything. The thing is that the software wants me to connect pads but once it's done it doesn't seem to recognize the connection and is claiming this is a <0.254 mm violation. As if connecting multi layer pads together is not possible. even if they are from the same net. For information I don’t have anything on the bottom side yet expect the multilayer pads.
Is there some kind of rule that produce this error?

A better place to ask software-questions is the Altium forums.

It seems you just drew some lines and didn't use the proper routing tools to make your traces.

It looks like the net name isn't matching up, you have imported the nets, you can see the rats nest. Make sure the net names match up on the traces, if they don't then relabel the net names with the proper net name matching the pad.
Also try and hit the wire button (ctrl-w I believe by default) and route the traces.
